# android file upload with retrofit to asp.net web api

Tags: android, asp.net-web-api, file-upload, retrofit2, multipartform-data

I'm trying to make a file upload with a picture and an string parameter, the file gets upload successfuly, but the string paremeter is always null. Could someone else help me please? Thanks in advance!

```
//Retrofit Interface
@Multipart
@POST("account/imageupload")
Call<ResponseBody> uploadProfilePicture(@Part MultipartBody.Part file, 
@Part("userid") RequestBody userid);

//Activity
ApiClient apiClient = new ApiClient(token.getAccessToken(), "multipart/form-data");
            ApiInterface apiService = apiClient.getClient().create(ApiInterface.class);

            File file = new File(selectedImagePath);
            RequestBody reqFile = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse(getContentResolver().getType(selectedImageUri)), file);
            MultipartBody.Part body = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("file", file.getName(), reqFile);

            RequestBody user = RequestBody.create(MultipartBody.FORM, token.getUserId());

            Call<ResponseBody> call = apiService.uploadProfilePicture(body, user);
            call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {
                    int statusCode = response.code();
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
                    String message = t.getMessage();
                }
            });

    //Web API (C# web api)
    [Route("imageupload")]
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> UploadProfilePicture([FromBody] 
    Models.ProfilePhotoUpload photo)
    {
        WriteImage(photo.file);            
        return Ok();
    }

    //Api Controller Model
    public class ProfilePhotoUpload
    {
        string userid { get; set; }
        public HttpFile file { get; set; }
    }
```

The problem is that the file gets uploaded correctly, but the userid parameter is always null.

[image: web api controller action]

Comment: I think your android code working fine there is some problem on ASP.net code.

Comment: Oh, you were right Haresh, my api model userid property was missing the public modifier, i set it as public now and everything works fine... Thanks a lot!

Comment: Great good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating incorrect RequestBody for text

Try this:

```
  RequestBody user = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), token.getUserId());
```

Comment: that was my userid property missing the public modifier Hitesh, now it works fine! Thanks a lot for your help!